# Creating a string and converting it to JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a situation where I need to parse a string, break, rejoin and then generate jsx from it. I'm somewhat successful but I have to make it clickable as well so that I can navigate on click but the problem is `onClick` remains a string even after conversion.

Here's the details:

I get a string in this format:

**Some Text** @(username)[a_long_user_id_to_navigate_to] **some more text**

I first get all the mentions from text and convert it to object of usernames with their IDs.

and then:

```
const createMessageWithActionableMentions = (message, mentions) => {
    mentions.map(mention => {
        message = message.replace('@'+'['+mention.username+']'+'('+mention.id+')',`<span style="color:${Colors.colorPrimary}; cursor: pointer" onClick={props.history.push('/some-route')}>@${mention.username}</span>`)
    })
    return message
}
```

the `message` argument in above function contains the raw string and the `mentions` is an array of objects as follows:

```
mentions = [
    {
        username: 'abcd_1234',
        id: 'abcd_defg_hijk'
    },
    {
        username: 'efgh_1234',
        id: 'wxyz_defg_jklm'
    }
    ...so on
]
```

Here's what I do when I add this text to view:

`<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: message}}></p>`

Here's what I see on webpage:

`Some text @username some more text`

Here's what I see on Inspector:

`<span style="color:#03F29E; cursor: pointer" onclick="{props.history.push('/some-route')}">@username</span>`

Now the question is how do I handle this part `onclick="{props.history.push('/some-route')}` to work the react way. also, am I doing it correctly or there's a better way?

Comment: Why are you using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` when you could just write the whole thing in JSX and make it much more efficient?

Comment: @mousetail when I do this: ```message = message.replace('@'+'['+mention.username+']'+'('+mention.id+')',<span style={{color:Colors.colorPrimary, cursor: 'pointer'}}>@{mention.username}</span>)``` I get that: ```Some text [object Object] some more text``` how do I deal with this?

Comment: You are returning a string, not JSX. Don't put HTML in strings in react

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
const createMessageWithActionableMentions = (message, mentions) => {
    // Will return a list of JSX elements
    let output = [message];

    // For every mention
    mentions.map(
        mention=>`@[${mention.username}](${mention.id})`
    ).forEach(mention => {
        // For every string we have output so far
        output = output.map(
            substring => {
                // Exclude existing JSX elements or strings that do not contain the mention
                if (typeof substring!=="string" || !substring.includes(mention)) return [substring]
                // We know the mention exists in this specific string segment so we need to find where it is so we can cut it out
                const index = substring.indexOf(mention)
                // Split the string into the part before, the part after, and the JSX element
                return [
                    substring.substring(0,index),
                    <span style={{color:Colors.colorPrimary; cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={()=>props.history.push('/some-route')}>{mention.username}</span>,
                    substring.substring(index+mention.length)
                ]
            }
        // Reduce the nested array of arrays back into a single array
        ).reduce((a,b)=>[...a,...b], [])
    })
    return output
}
```

No Inner html shenanigens needed. Just use it like this:

```
<p>{message}</p>
```

Comment: Well, this is kinda messed up. You initially mapped the mentions to message as ```output``` wrote some code that probably does something. and returned the raw string that was passed as message argument initially. Modifying this solution in order for it to work will basically go back to my initial solution but with more lines of code. Thank you for the solution though.

Comment: The initial version was like that but it has been fixed over 20 minutes ago

Comment: Unlike your example the event handlers work here and you avoid using `innerHTML` which is very unsecure and slow. What if your original `message` included some HTML? It would break the page

Comment: lemme explain my mention once again initially the mention is like this: ** @[username](some_long_user_id) and when passed to ```createMessageWithActionableMentions``` as a parameter the```mentions``` actually is an object I.e. mentions = [{username:user_abc, id:abcd_efgh_ijkl}] now look at your solution. This is not going to work.

Comment: I fixed it to compute the string representation of the mention

Answer (score 0):

You can add click handlers to those spans using Vanilla JS as following:

1. Assign a class to those spans, for example `user-mention`

```js
const createMessageWithActionableMentions = (message, mentions) => {
  mentions.map(mention => {
      message = message.replace('@'+'['+mention.username+']'+'('+mention.id+')',`<span style="color:${Colors.colorPrimary}; cursor: pointer" class="user-mention">@${mention.username}</span>`)
  })
  return message
}
```

2. Add event listeners to those spans. If you are using function components with hooks, put it inside a useEffect like this, and make sure this effect hook is called after the spans are appended to the DOM.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName('user-mention')].forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
      props.history.push('/some-route');
    })
  })
}, [/* Your dependencies */])
```

Note that if the spans change (increase/decrease in number, for example), you need to handle event listeners when they change as well. If this becomes cumbersome, you can use [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, this can be solved using the array, I simply first broken the message into array of substrings:

```
message = message.split(' ')
```

Then mapped it to find mentions in those substrings and replaced the respective `substr` with `<span>`:

```
message.map( (substr, index) => {
        if(isMention(substr))){
            found = mentions.find(mention => mention.username == substr.split('[').pop().split(']')[0])
            if(found) {
                message[index] = <span style={{color:Colors.colorPrimary, cursor: "pointer"}}>{found.username}</span>
            }
        }
    })
```

The final code

```
const createMessageWithActionableMentions = (message, mentions) => {
    let found = ''
    message = message.split(' ')
    message.map( (substr, index) => {
        if(isMention(substr))){
            found = mentions.find(mention => mention.username == substr.split('[').pop().split(']')[0])
            if(found) {
                message[index] = <span style={{color:Colors.colorPrimary, cursor: "pointer"}}>{found.username}</span>
            }
        }
    })
    return message
}
```

Then rendered it as jsx

```
<p>{message}</p>
```

Comment: This will only work if the mention is delimited by a space. If it is at the end of the line it will fail. Also it will fail if the mention is surrounded by punctuation.